# How to make background photo change automatically after 5 seconds in asp.net + bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How can the background pic of my page change after 5 seconds?
I was thinking to use carousel with twitter bootstrap. But every example I've seen so far is to change the image when I press the next button.

What is the best to do it? should I focus just with asp.net and css file to make this? and the code behind on C#, or add javascript or jquery?

Comment: Please check the sample provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap `carousel` with `data-interval="5000"` to set the time where `5000` is in `milli seconds` equals to `5 seconds`.

Smaple code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
 
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```